# Prevent two events to happen simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

**About**: there are two threads running - one check for timeout (inactivity for some time), another one is where user works with UI.
**Problem**: timeout event occured slightly before user action, even though at the same millisecond, based on logs I can see it

```
2018-03-15 16:58:54:921 INFO  <main> {Thread-58} [InputTimeoutThread] Input timeout occured.
2018-03-15 16:58:54:921 DEBUG <main> {AWT-EventQueue-1} [INPUT_EVENT] Input event : functionKeyID = 10056
2018-03-15 16:58:54:921 DEBUG <main> {AWT-EventQueue-1} [FunctionManagerImpl] Calling function [ID (10056)]
```

**Result**: inconsistent results as because of timeout logout event was called, but at the same time user action was done.
If timeout had happened before the user action it would have blocked the user to do any action, but this did not happen here as you can see.

Can anyone please advise how to tackle this? So that it can be guaranteed: no actions possible after some event happaned (in different threads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some technique for stransferring data between threads. For example, you can use volatile primitive:
`private volatile boolean isTimeoutElapsed = false;`
Then in thread with timeout you can do:

```
isTimeoutElapsed = true;
```

and in UI thread:

```
if (!isTimeoutElapsed)
{
    doAction();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lock for this.

```
Lock myLock = new ReentrantLock();
```

In your Timeout and other thread call

```
myLock.lock();
try
{
    // code
}
finally
{
    myLock.unlock();
}
```

Just lock the lock before you do your timeout code and when you want to handle input.

Using a volatile boolean flag is probably more efficient though as you aren't paying lock overhead whenever you are handling input.